# Drools rule engine validation service KnowledgeBuilder initialization error

Tags: java, drools

I have a problem regarding KnowledgeBuilder initialization within a business service called from a RestEasy  web service.

More specifically I have to create a "createUser" business service that needs to apply some validations on the user specific parameters.

All goes fine until a need to initialize KnowledgeBuilder drools specific class

```
KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
```

I do not know the cause of this exception, but I think that this can only occur due to some mismatched dependencies... although the drools libraries used are the ultimate release.

**Thank you in advance!**

Business Service class

```
@Override
public void create(String userName, String firstName, String lastName, String email, String locale) throws UserProfileException
{
    UserProfile userProfile = new UserProfile();
    userProfile.setUserName(userName);
    userProfile.setFirstName(firstName);
    userProfile.setLastName(lastName);
    userProfile.setEmail(email);
    userProfile.setPreferredLocale(locale);

    //initialization --- error occurs at bellow line
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("userProfileValidation.drl"), ResourceType.DRL);
    KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();
    if (errors.size() > 0)
    {
        for (KnowledgeBuilderError error : errors)
        {
            System.err.println(error);

        }
        throw new UserProfileException("Could not parse knowledge.");
    }
    KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    StatefulKnowledgeSession session = kbase.newStatefulKnowledgeSession();

    //use
    session.insert(userProfile);
    session.insert(errors);
    session.fireAllRules();
    session.dispose();

    if (errors.size() == 0)
    {
        userProfileDao.save(userProfile);
    }
}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <drools.version>6.1.0.Final</drools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wkfsfrc.morpheus.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>dao</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>${drools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

Full stack trace:

```
18:30:25,899 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-6) UT005023: Exception handling request to /webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/user/create: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate service for Class 'org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService'
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:76) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:212) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:149) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:372) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:179) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:220) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate service for Class 'org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryService'
    at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl.get(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:161) [drools-api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.loadServiceFactory(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:131) [drools-api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.getKnowledgeBuilderServiceFactory(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:125) [drools-api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.drools.builder.KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(KnowledgeBuilderFactory.java:47) [drools-api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at com.wkfsfrc.morpheus.platform.business.service.UserBusinessServiceImpl.create(UserBusinessServiceImpl.java:47) [business-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at com.wkfsfrc.morpheus.platform.rest.service.UserRestService.createUser(UserRestService.java:47) [rest-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:137) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:296) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:250) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:237) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:356) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar:]
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to instantiate 'org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl'
    at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl$ReflectionInstantiator.newInstance(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:209) [drools-api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl$ReflectionInstantiator.call(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:201) [drools-api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl.get(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:159) [drools-api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderFactoryServiceImpl from [Module "deployment.webapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at org.drools.util.ServiceRegistryImpl$ReflectionInstantiator.newInstance(ServiceRegistryImpl.java:206) [drools-api-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    ... 47 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably worth pointing out that you're using the wrong `drools-api` version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When everything else is referring to `${drools.version}`, which is 6.1.0.Final.

Note that "drools-api" is now "kie-api". The dependency you should be using is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
    <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
    <version>${drools.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Although, it may also be worth just removing that dependency to see whether you even need it.

Comment: That's weird ... I have a project referring to that one without any problem. Will double check.

Comment: Ah ... I just spotted that it's now called "knowledge-api". Although I'm not so sure that you actually need it anyway.

Comment: Drools 6 uses the KIE-* API (org.drools:kie-api).
If you want to continue using the Drools 5.x Knowledge-* API, you will need org.drools:knowledge-api, which is a wrapper delegating to the kie-api anyway.
The drools-api is indeed out of place.